# What is the meaning of "sleep arousal" and "unchanted" at this comic page?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

1. "Also, you have a level of sleep arousal that, at this point in our relationship, does nothing for me."
2. "You need to be alert. We're entering The Unchanted Forest".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"sleep [arousal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arousal)": some men get an [erection](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/erection) when asleep. He has fallen asleep and is sitting close behind her, and she can feel his erection against her back. Eeeeww!

"Unchanted": as it explains in the text, it used to be called the [enchanted](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enchanted) forest, but that "seemed a little silly". Unchanted is a made up word.